# Can I recover my thumb drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I was using my thumb drive when I saw a hidden folder named `System Volume Information`. I deleted this folder thinking it was a virus. After doing that, the windows explorer window disappeared and I was unable to open the drive in windows explorer. So I decided to format this drive. Now format returned an error stating `Disk no longer exists`.

Now when I plug this drive in, I see the lights on the drive turn on, but it doesn't get displayed in the My Computer section.

If I open Disk Management via snap-in console, I see

```
Capacity  : 0MB
Partition Style : MBR
Status : No Media
```

but no options to format it.

Can I recover my drive's 4GB space or have I lost my drive forever?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `Computer Management`, `Disk Management` to remove the existing partition, then create a new partition. After that, it should be possible again to see and format the drive.

Alternatively, there are tools specifically for formatting an USB drive, but they may still need to first create remove/create the partition.

Comment: I donot see any partitions. Only the device with 0MB capacity. No disk, no disk space and absolutely nothing on the explorer

Comment: To the left of the disk there is a grey panel, right click it to see the options. E.g. This image: http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/up/sshot-2009-08-27-15-50-21.png - the panel that says "Disk 0" - but get your USB disk!!!